# Running External Program in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, runtime.exec

I am able to print the output of an external program in Eclipse via the code below (found online, not mine). I would like to be able to pass a command to the program and THEN print the output of the program but I don't know how to pass commands to the program. Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks!

Code:

```
String line;
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("Z:/LPCXpresso/test10/Debug/arm-none-eabi-readelf.exe");
BufferedReader bri = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
BufferedReader bre = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
while ((line = bri.readLine()) != null) {
     System.out.println(line);
}
bri.close();
while ((line = bre.readLine()) != null) {
     System.out.println(line);
}
bre.close();
p.waitFor();
```

Comment: What do you mean by `pass a command`? just line a command line argument when launching or to interact with programm via its stdin once lauched?

Comment: If the program was running by itself (not through eclipse) and you entered "S", it would provide an output that I'd like to utilize in my project. So I guess I meant something to interact with the program once launched.

Answer (score 3):

First I would recommend using [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) instead of `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)`

Second to be able to interact with the different streams of the process started you need to do it concurrently, i.e. for each stream create an own Thread where you interact with it.

Here is a sample code wihch illustrates interaction with the command line prompt in windows `cmd.exe`

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe");
    Process proc = pb.start();

    // handle each of proc's streams in a separate thread
    ExecutorService handlerThreadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);


    handlerThreadPool.submit(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // we want to write to the stdin of the process
            BufferedWriter stdin = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(proc.getOutputStream()));

            // read from our own stdin so we can write it to proc's stdin
            BufferedReader myStdin = 
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String line = null;
            try {
                do {
                    line = myStdin.readLine();
                    stdin.write(String.format("%s%n", line));
                    stdin.flush();
                } while(! "exit".equalsIgnoreCase(line));
            } catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });



    handlerThreadPool.submit(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // we want to read the stdout of the process
            BufferedReader stdout = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            try {
                while(null != (line = stdout.readLine())) {
                    System.out.printf("[stdout] %s%n", line);
                }
            } catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    handlerThreadPool.submit(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // we want to read the stderr of the process
            BufferedReader stderr = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));
            String line;
            try {
                while(null != (line = stderr.readLine())) {
                    System.err.printf("[stderr] %s%n", line);
                }
            } catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    // wait for the process to terminate
    int exitCode = proc.waitFor();
    System.out.printf("Process terminated with exit code %d%n", exitCode);
    handlerThreadPool.shutdown();
}
```

You could make it simple and redirect of the process `stderr` to `stdout` using [ProcessBuilder#redirectErrorStream(true)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectErrorStream-boolean-) before starting the process and then have only 2 threads, one for input and one for output